# combine output by field using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that was created using `awk` in the format below:

**file**

```
chr2:46603668-46603902 EPAS1-902|gc=54.3 234 bases with an average of 253.1
chr2:211471445-211471675 CPS1-1205|gc=48.3 230 bases with an average of 264.7
chr19:15291762-15291983 NOTCH3-1003|gc=68.8 221 bases with an average of 195.8
chr2:211460199-211460318 CPS1-1200|gc=41.2 119 bases with an average of 105.6
```

What I am trying to do is combine all `$2` that match in rows on after another and strip off the `-`.  Each row in the file will have a match, though thats not shown in the example. Thank you :).

**desired output**

```
chr2:211471445-211471675 CPS1|gc=48.3 230 bases with an average of 264.7 
chr2:211460199-211460318 CPS1|gc=41.2 119 bases with an average of 105.6
chr2:46603668-46603902 EPAS1-902|gc=54.3 234 bases with an average of 253.1
chr19:15291762-15291983 NOTCH3-1003|gc=68.8 221 bases with an average of 195.8
```

I tried:

**awk**

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2; a[k]+=split[$2] "-"; c[k]++}
END{for(k in a)
      {split(k,ks,FS);
       print ks[1],c[k],ks[2],a[k]/c[k]}}' file > output.txt
```

Comment: If "each row will have a match", why don't you just strip off the "-[digits]" in the 2nd field directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `sort` in addition to `awk` is an option, you might want to try:

```
sort -k2,2 file | awk '{sub(/-[0-9]+/,"",$2);print $0}'
```

The `-k2,2` is to specify the second column. The output in this case is:

```
chr2:211460199-211460318 CPS1|gc=41.2 119 bases with an average of 105.6
chr2:211471445-211471675 CPS1|gc=48.3 230 bases with an average of 264.7
chr2:46603668-46603902 EPAS1|gc=54.3 234 bases with an average of 253.1
chr19:15291762-15291983 NOTCH3|gc=68.8 221 bases with an average of 195.8
```

Note that I stripped "-" **and** the trailing numbers in the second field. In your desired output you did this for the `CPS1`-values but not for the others. What am I missing here? If you want to delete only `-`, replace `/-[0-9]+/` by `/-/`

If you do not want to or cannot use `sort`, you could consider `gawk`. Contrary to `awk`, `gawk` has built-in functions to sort an array (`asort` and `asorti`). In this case, your gawk command:

```
gawk '{sub(/-[0-9]+/,"",$2); ar[$2]=$0}
            END{n = asort(ar)
                for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                     print ar[i]}' file
```

The output:

```
chr19:15291762-15291983 NOTCH3|gc=68.8 221 bases with an average of 195.8
chr2:211460199-211460318 CPS1|gc=41.2 119 bases with an average of 105.6
chr2:211471445-211471675 CPS1|gc=48.3 230 bases with an average of 264.7
chr2:46603668-46603902 EPAS1|gc=54.3 234 bases with an average of 253.1
```

Still want to use awk and awk only? In this case, you have to implement your own sorting function. Read [here](http://awk.info/?Sorting) how to do this.

Thanks to mklement0 for some suggestions regarding the use of `sort`'s -k  option and `awk`'s -F option.

Comment: Thank you very much for that very helpful post :).